Vercel : Connection problems via Next-Auth + MongoDB
I have a problem with the production installation on 'Vercel'. The problem is related to the use of Mongoose + MongoDB, at least that's what I saw in my logs on 'Vercel'. I've tested this application locally and in production on OVH and no problem. But I'm trying to install it on 'Vercel' in a more user-friendly way. The problem is that I can't connect to this platform. MongoDB is on Atlas and accessible from all platforms. This application is developed entirely with NextJs. I'd really like a hand debugging this application. I put the NextAuth programs first 'src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js' :
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import authOptions from "@/app/api/auth/authOptions";

const  handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

Then 'src/app/api/auth/authOptions.js' :
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { connectMongoose } from "@/utils/mongodb";
import {  UserModel } from "@/models";
import * as bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@auth/mongodb-adapter";
import clientPromise from "@/utils/adapterMongoDb";

const authOptions = {
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
  pages: {
    signIn: "/connexion",
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  },
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
      allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking: true,
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credidentials",
      credentials: {
        username: {
          label: "Username",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "Votre email",
        },
        password: {
          label: "Password",
          type: "password",
        },
      },
        async authorize(credentials) {
            await connectMongoose();
            const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email: credentials?.username })
              .lean()
              .exec();
            if (!user) {
              throw new Error("L'email n'est pas enregistré...")
            } else if (user?.emailVerified === null ) {
              throw new Error("L'email n'est pas vérifié...")
            } else if (!user?.password) {
              throw new Error("Créer votre mot de passe...")
            };

            const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(
              credentials.password,
              user.password
            );

            if (!isPasswordCorrect) throw new Error("Vous avez entrer un mauvais mot de passe");

            const { password, _id, __v, emailVerified, ...userWithoutPass } = user;
            return userWithoutPass;
        },
      }),
      ],
      
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile }) {

      if (user && account?.provider === "google") {
        const userPerso = await UserModel.findOne({ email: profile.email }).lean().exec();
        if (!userPerso) {
          if (profile.email === "davidlaunay567@gmail.com" || profile.email === <email> ) {let role = "admin"}
          await UserModel.create({
            id: profile.sub,
            email: profile.email,
            phone: "",
            firstName: profile.given_name,
            lastName: profile.family_name,
            image: profile.picture,
            name: profile.name,
            emailVerified: profile.email_verified === true ? new Date() : null,
            role: role ? role : "user",
          });
        } else {
          await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
          {email: profile.email},
          {$set : 
            {
              firstName: user?.firstName ? user.firstName : profile.given_name,
              lastName: user?.lastName ? user.lastName : profile.family_name,
              image: profile.picture,
              emailVerified: user.emailVerified === null && profile.email_verified === true ? new Date() : user.emailVerified,
            }
          },
          { upsert: true},
        ).lean().exec();
      }
        const { id, password, _id, __v, emailVerified, ...userWithoutPass } = user;
        token.user = userWithoutPass;

        return token;
      } else if (user && account?.provider === "credentials") {
        token.user = user;
        return token;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
        session.user = token?.user;
        session.accessToken = token?.accessToken;
      return session;
    },
  },
};

export default authOptions;


Then 'src/utils/mongodb.js' :
import { MongoClient, Mongoose } from 'mongodb';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI;

if (!MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Invalid/Missing environment variable: "MONGODB_URI"');
}

let cachedClient = null;
let cachedDb = null;

export async function connectToDatabase() {
  if (cachedClient && cachedDb) {
    return { client: cachedClient, db: cachedDb };
  }

  const client = new MongoClient(MONGODB_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
    socketTimeoutMS: 45000,
  });

  await client.connect();

  const db = client.db();
  cachedClient = client;
  cachedDb = db;

  return { client, db };
}

// mongoose connection
let isConnected = false;

export async function connectMongoose() {
  if (isConnected) {
    console.log("MongoDB est déjà connectée.");
    return;
  }

  try {
    console.log("Connection à MongoDB...");
    await mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, {
      serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 50000, // Augmentez à 50 secondes
    });
    isConnected = true;
    console.log("MongoDB connection est connectée maitenant.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error connection à MongoDB:", error);
    throw new Error("Error connection à MongoDB définitivement");
  }
}

Finally 'src/utils/adapterMongoDb.js'
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Invalid/Missing environment variable: "MONGODB_URI"');
}

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const options = {
  serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 50000,
};

let client;
let clientPromise;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
    global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
  }
  clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise;
} else {
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
  clientPromise = client.connect();
}

export default clientPromise;

Log from 'Vercel' '/api/auth/callback/google' :
[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_HANDLER_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_handler_error Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms {
  message: 'Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms',
  stack: 'MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms\n' +
    '    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:185:23)\n' +
    '    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:581:17)\n' +
    '    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:519:7)',
  name: 'MongooseError'
}

Thank you very much in advance
My site is in production on OVH https://buzz-ready.com but I still have 20 days to transfer to 'Vercel'. I've attached the 'package.json' :
{
  "name": "ha-couverture-next",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 3001",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 3001",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "format": "prettier --write ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth/mongodb-adapter": "^3.0.0",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.4",
    "@next/third-parties": "^14.1.2",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.11.97",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.14",
    "@types/react-transition-group": "^4.4.10",
    "@vercel/analytics": "^1.3.1",
    "@vercel/speed-insights": "^1.0.12",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "cookies-next": "^4.2.1",
    "date-fns": "^3.6.0",
    "googleapis": "^134.0.0",
    "idna-uts46-hx": "^6.0.4",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mongod": "^2.0.0",
    "mongodb": "^6.5.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.3.3",
    "next": "^14.1.2",
    "next-auth": "^4.24.7",
    "next-connect": "^1.0.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.9",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwind": "^2.2.12",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.3",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.50.1",
    "react-responsive": "^9.0.2",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.5",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
    "sass": "^1.70.0",
    "sharp": "^0.33.2",
    "utils": "^0.3.1",
    "yup": "^1.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/bun": "latest",
    "@types/gtag.js": "^0.0.20",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.4.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3"
  }
}



I have found the solution, I just to add 1 ligne 'await connectMongoose();' before 'const userPerso = await UserModel.findOne({ email: profile.email }).lean().exec();'
